# Converting list numpy array to normal array for CNN-Keras

Tags: python, numpy, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have some images separated by folders. So I imported them and converted to them array of pixels. When I type in:

```
In [9]: X_train.shape
out [9]: (7467,60,80,3)
```

I wanted to append this with the no. of classes, create a dataset and save as `.json` file and import in a fresh notebook and do image processing for my own project purpose.
 So I typed in this code:

```
In [10]: dataset = pd.DataFrame({'label': y_train, 'images': list(X_train)}, 
         columns=['label', 'images'])
```

However when I type in:

```
In [11]: X_train
Out [11]: array([[[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        ...,
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        ...,
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        ...,
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0.]],

       ...,
```

But when I import the json file and show:

```
In [2]: train=pd.read_json('train_file.json')
        train.head()
Out [2]:
 image_no   images
0    7468   [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0039215...
1    7469   [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0,...
10   7478   [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0,...
100  7568   [[[0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0,...
1000 8468   [[[0.27058823530000004, 0.1843137255, 0.247058.
```

..

And when I type in:

```
In [3]: train['images].values
Out [3]: array([list([[[0.7411764706, 0.7607843137, 0.8274509804], `[0.7215686275000001, 0.7058823529, 0.7882352941], [0.7019607843, 0.6823529412, 0.7843137255], [0.7176470588, 0.7215686275000001, 0.8196078431], [0.8, 0.8352941176, 0.8549019608], [0.8352941176, 0.8666666667, 0.8666666667], [0.8509803922, 0.8745098039, 0.8666666667], [0.8549019608, 0.8745098039, 0.8666666667], [0.8431372549, 0.8666666667, 0.8666666667], [0.8235294118, 0.8705882353000001, 0.8588235294000001], [0.831372549, 0.8705882353000001, 0.8627450980000001], [0.8352941176, 0.831372549, 0.8549019608], [0.7686274510000001, 0.7686274510000001, 0.8117647059], [0.7098039216, 0.7254901961, 0.7803921569000001], [0.7019607843, 0.7333333333000001, 0.8], [0.7254901961, 0.7686274510000001, 0.8392156863], [0.7647058824, 0.7803921569000001, 0.8509803922], [0.7372549020000001, 0.7411764706, 0.8117647059], [0.7098039216, 0.7019607843, 0.7960784314], [0.6980392157, 0.6705882353, 0.8039215686000001], [0.6901960784000001, 0.6823529412, 0.8117647059], [0.6901960784000001, 0.6901960784000001, 0.8196078431], [0.6941176471, 0.6980392157, 0.831372549], [0.6980392157, 0.7058823529, 0.8352941176], [0.7254901961, 0.7490196078, 0.8352941176], [0.8, 0.831372549, 0.8745098039], [0.8431372549, 0.8784313725, 0.8862745098], [0.8509803922, 0.8823529412000001, 0.8862745098], [0.831372549, 0.8352941176, 0.8745098039], [0.7725490196, 0.7411764706, 0.8392156863], [0.7529411765, 0.7294117647, 0.8392156863], [0.7607843137, 0.7764705882, 0.8352941176], [0.8078431373, 0.8392156863, 0.8705882353000001], [0.8274509804, 0.8549019608, 0.8862745098], [0.8117647059, 0.8431372549, 0.8705882353000001], [0.7725490196, 0.8, 0.8352941176], [0.7529411765, 0.7764705882, 0.8431372549], [0.8117647059, 0.8352941176, 0.8862745098], [0.8745098039, 0.8980392157, 0.9176470588000001], [0.8862745098, 0.9098039216, 0.9058823529000001], [0.8823529412000001, 0.9058823529000001, 0.9019607843], [0.8784313725, 0.9098039216, 0.9058823529000001], [0.8666666667, 0.9137254902, 0.9058823529000001], [0.8627450980000001, 0.9176470588000001, 0.9098039216], [0.86274509....`
```

And when I type in:

```
In [4]: train['images'].shape
Out [4]: (7467,)
```

But I'm able to plot these images using `plt.imshow()`. But when I try to directly do `model.fit(train['images],y_train)`
I get this error:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

So where am I going wrong? While dumping it to a `.json` file or how can I convert it to an array after importing the `json` file and fix the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `np arrays` are converted to lists when storing the dataframe as a `.json`. To feed them to your Keras model, you need to have them in one `array` of shape `(images, height, width, channels)`:

```
X_train = np.array(train['images'].tolist())
```

Comment: `X_train.shape` still remains `(7467,)` and is giving error `Error when checking input: expected conv2d_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (7467, 1)`

Comment: You are right. Try: `X_train = np.array(train['images'].tolist())`. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Hi, i did `model.predict(X_test)` and I get an output with array of probabilities. Do you know how I can convert them to class number and then map them to string values?

Comment: To convert to binary labels: `(model.predict(X_test) > 0.5).astype(int)`. To convert to string labels, you can use a python dictionary that maps the binary labels to the string names.

Comment: Yes, i've been able to solve that but new problem is my model is predicting only one output class constantly. Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: That might be related to your data, the way you train your model et cetera. This is outside the scope of this discussion. You can search on stackoverflow, there are topics with similar questions.